# Cell comment does not get displayed on MS office though it comes on open office

Tags: apache-poi

Here is the sample code to create tool tip for the cell

```
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Comment comment = drawing.createCellComment(anchor);
    RichTextString strCmt = factory.createRichTextString("Tool tipssssssssssss");
    comment.setString(strCmt);
    comment.setAuthor("Rinkalkumar");
```

This part of code sets tool tip to cell

Problem is it gets displayed on open office not on MS office

Any solutions to overcome this problem?

I am using poi-3.6.

Comment: Have you tried with Apache POI 3.8 beta 3? You might find it's been fixed since 3.6.

Comment: Thanks Gagravarr i upgraded POI 3.6 to POI 3.7 now comment works on both open office and MS office too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the trick to solve this problem is to upgrade to a newer copy of POI (3.7 at a minimum, ideally 3.8 only out, or one of it's betas for now)